# Kaehler varieties

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X\rightarrow D$ be a proper holomorphic map of complex-analytic spaces that is a submersion away from the origin. Suppose that the central fiber is the analytification of a reduced scheme projective over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that non-central fibers are all smooth.

Are they necessarily Kaehler in some small neighbourhood of the origin? Is there some notion of "Kaehler variety" such that the same is true if the central fiber is merely a Kaehler variety?

Any reference would be appreciated.